# How to find which threads currently hold java.util.concurrent.Semaphore permits?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, semaphore, thread-dump

I am trying to analyze a thread dump which seems to indicate that there are numerous threads that are waiting on [java.util.concurrent.Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) permits, i.e., the threads are waiting on Semaphore.acquire().

This I was able to imply because the threads are in WAITING (parking) state, and from what I've understood, Semaphore's do not use LOCK monitors, but use [LockSupport.park()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html#park()) instead, waiting on another thread to unpark it.

Now, is there a way to imply from a thread dump on what all threads currently hold the Semaphore permits?

Similar to finding threads in BLOCKED state, and check which is the thread that holds the LOCK which is causing the thread to BLOCK?

Comment: There is nothing really held when you acquire a permit; there is nothing to give back when you release it. No thread actually holds anything - it is simply a counter. e.g. a semaphore can start with zero permits and you can legally call release.

Comment: @Andy Turner Exactly, so can I simply conclude that it is impossible to find which threads have acquired the permit successfully via a thread dump?

Comment: @aathif semaphores are not aware of threads, which is what makes them particularly lightweight (and useful in asynchronous programming). A thread can release a semaphore without ever having acquired it. There is no concept of ownership. You'll have to do it the hard way and analyse the stack trace to find where they're waiting and go from there.

Comment: @Voo Right, that is a precise explanation. Maybe you should actually add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semaphores do not have a concept of ownership or know anything about threads. This makes them particularly lightweight (and useful in asynchronous programming where your logical *thread of execution* and the hardware thread on which it is executed won't necessarily have a 1:1 mapping).

You can also see this from the fact that a thread can release a semaphore without ever having acquired it.

You will have to look at the stacktraces to see where on what semaphores the threads are waiting and work backwards from there.

Answer (score 0):

There are tools that help you to analyse dumps.Yourkit is one such tool that can be used to analyse blocked threads.

Reference:
https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/monitor_profiling.jsp

Comment: I am aware of such thread dump analyzers. It would be great if you could write on how YourKit would be help me in finding which threads have semaphore permits causing contention.

Comment: Yourkit can be used for analyzing threads as well as monitors.
In Yourkit you will find a Threads tab allows you to view the state(waiting,blocked,etc)of all the threads.It also tells you if it is a daemon thread and a lot more.
For viewing monitor usage details 
In Yourkit goto View->Monitor Usage.       Not sure though if you could get the details of semaphore permits.